# How do I use spring data jpa to query json column in MYSQL using Specification?

Tags: sql, mysql, hibernate, jpa, specifications

i wanna get field *pattern* from json structure using JPA Specification. I use database MYSQL.
that's what I wrote, but it doesn't work:

```
 public static Specification<GameConfig> whereLettersContainByPattern(Specification<GameConfig> spec, String arg) {
        if (arg == null || arg.isEmpty()) {
            return null;}
        return spec.and(
                (root, query, cb) ->  cb.equal(
                cb.function(
                        "JSON_SEARCH",
                        String.class,
                        root.<String>get("prizeLineConfig"),
                        cb.literal("pattern")
                ),
                arg
        ));
    }
```

My response entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "game_configs")
public class GameConfig {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Type(JsonType.class)
    @Column(name = "prize_line_config")
    private String prizeLineConfig;
}
```

But i get error

```
 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'JSON_SEARCH'
```